# Invalid field Account for Contact

Tags: apex, account, contact, fields, sobjectexception

I have a code snippet that runs like so:

```
Id accountId;

public SObject getContact(){
  Contact toReturn = new Contact();
  toReturn = fillInRequiredValues(toReturn);
  toReturn.Account = accountId;
  insert toReturn;
  return toReturn;
}
```

But whenever it's ran, I get the error: `System.SObjectException: Invalid field Account for Contact`, when account is clearly the first field in contact. It seems like this is highly an error on the back end, but I cannot be sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you want to set is `AccountId`. You can [set a lookup via name pointing reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/set-relationship-via-name-pointing-field) (`Account` in this case), but you just have the Id here.

```
toReturn.AccountId = accountId;
```

Comment: why does apex do this? would it not be simpler to just name the field 'Account' ?

Comment: I find their naming conventions quite sensible. You can either do `Account record = toReturn.Account` or `Id accountId = toReturn.AccountId`. It makes sense to me.