# for loop query to populate lookup

Tags: apex, query, externalid, compile-error

I am upserting a custom object record and I want to populate a lookup field. My thinking is that I need to do a query in the for loop get the id then push that to an id variable (externalid). Then finally when I go to upsert just say lookup__c = external id

The object in the lookup has an external id, can I just search on that in the upsert call?

If not, I wrote this bit of code to get the id and then pass it through if there is a result. When I try to compile I get:

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject ListProduct_Structure__c

How can I get this lookup populated the most efficiently?

```
List<Product_Structure__c> prodStructure = [SELECT Id 
                                            FROM Product_Structure__c
                                            WHERE External_Id__c = :field__c LIMIT 1];
        if(
            prodStructure != null){
            externalId.add(valueof(prodStructure.Id));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List<SObject>` does not have an `Id` property. You can get the first record from the list instead, in this case.

```
List<MyObject__c> records = [/*query*/];
if (!records.isEmpty())
{
    Id recordId = records[0].Id;
    // further processing
}
```

If you want to figure out how to upsert relationships based on an external id, take a look at [Set Relationship Via Name Pointing Field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/set-relationship-via-name-pointing-field) You actually don't even need to upsert. The basic idea is that if you know the external id of the parent, you can do:

```
MyObject__c record = new MyObject__c();
record.Parent__r = new Parent__c(External__c = '<external_id>');
insert record;
```