# Inserting Accounts and Contacts Simultaneously

Tags: api, administration, contact, insert, rootstock

Trying to insert a **new Account and it's Contact** (maybe multiple Contacts?) at the **same time**.

While researching this, I've come across various posts that are close to the solution, such as:

[Simultaneous Parent/Child Insert](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AaztIAC%20Simultaneous%20Parent/Child)

[One DML Operation](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092reIAA%20One%20DML%20Op)

My own idea would be (only good for a SINGLE contact unless I create multiple sets of these fields):

- Have equivelent fields for the needed-Contact on the Account (hidden)
  and then have Apex (or possibly Process Builder?) create the Account
  using those fields after the Account appears.

It may not even work for what I need *(the Rootstock MRP plugin we're using is going to immediately sync the Account to Customer, and it may not see the Contact "in time")*.  It's still two operations.  But it's the closest I have come up with.

Any idea?

Comment: Just add an External Id field on `Account` that you can specify.

Comment: You're implying that if I use an ExternalID field on Account, and put the same on the Contact record, I can use that to relate the two, without having to query for the Account ID?   That's still technically two inserts unless there is another part to this I'm unclear on.   :-/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an `External Id` field on `Account` that you can specify, you can [set the relationship via the Name Pointing Field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/set-relationship-via-name-pointing-field) (`Account`).

```
String externalId = '<some_value>';
Account namePointingReference = new Account(ExternalId__c=externalId);
Account parent = new Account(ExternalId__c=externalId, /*other fields*/);
Contact child1 = new Contact(Account=namePointingReference, /*other fields*/);
Contact child2 = new Contact(Account=namePointingReference, /*other fields*/);
insert new List<SObject> { parent, child1, child2 };
```

Note that you need to use a separate `Account` instance for the name pointing reference, because you can only specify the External Id field for the `SObject` you use in this way. This approach will only consume one `DML Statement` from your governor limits.

Comment: This answer got me thinking: Any idea how the triggers behave on this insert? Wich runs first? The account or the contacts? Are the contacts ids available on the account after trigger?

Comment: @FernandoGavinho Those would be very good questions to post separately. It does seem obvious the `Account` triggers run first, but I'm not sure about the latter question.

Comment: [Done](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148992/how-does-insertion-of-multiple-sobjects-behave) =D

Comment: Fascinating.   Thanks so much.  The referenced post (Name Pointing Field) was pretty fascinating.