# How does insertion of mixed sObjects behave?

Tags: apex, trigger, order-of-execution

Reading Adrian's [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/148975/11928) on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148974/inserting-accounts-and-contacts-simultaneously/) got me thinking about the behavior of insertion of multiple sObjects. How does salesforce handle the insertion in trigger context?

On the code below:

```
String externalId = '<some_value>';
Account namePointingReference = new Account(ExternalId__c=externalId);

Account parent = new Account(ExternalId__c=externalId, /*other fields*/);
Contact child1 = new Contact(Account=namePointingReference, /*other fields*/);
Contact child2 = new Contact(Account=namePointingReference, /*other fields*/);

insert new List<SObject> { parent, child1, child2 };
```

Wich triggers run first? Do we have access to the Contacts Ids on the after trigger of the account?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I set up a fresh org to test this scenario out and the behavior is as I would expect. `Account` trigger fires before `Contact`, and the child records are not defined in the `Account` triggers at all.

**Account Trigger**

```
trigger Account on Account (before insert, after insert)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        system.debug('Account beforeInsert');
    }
    if (trigger.isAfter)
    {
        system.debug('Account afterInsert');
        system.debug([SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()]);
    }
}
```

**Contact Trigger**

```
trigger Contact on Contact (before insert)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        system.debug('Contact beforeInsert');
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
String external = '1';
Account parent = new Account(External__c=external, Name='Acme');
Contact child = new Contact(Account=new Account(External__c=external), LastName='Doe');
insert new List<SObject> { parent, child };
```

**Log**

> USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|Account beforeInsert
> USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|Account afterInsert
> USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|(Account:{Id=00141000009hXaXAAU})
> USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|Contact beforeInsert

If I change the child verification query to direclty query `Contact`:

```
system.debug([SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()]);
```

the log still shows no child records:

> [10]|DEBUG|()

---

Interestingly, if you reverse the order of the objects in the list, the triggers do fire in that order. So **the triggers fire in the order specified**. And when you reverse the order in this way, the child records *do not get associated to the parent*.

> USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|Contact beforeInsert
> USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|Account beforeInsert
> USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|Account afterInsert
> USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|()

This behavior matches up with the `SOAP API Developer Guide`:

> ## [Creating Records for Different Object Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm#MixedSaveSection)
>
> You can create records for multiple object types, including custom objects, in one call with API version 20.0 and later. For example, you could create a contact and an account in one call. You can create records for up to 10 object types in one call.
>
> Records are saved in the same order that they are entered in the sObjects input array. If you are entering new records that have a parent-child relationship, the parent record must precede the child record in the sObjects array. For example, if you are creating a contact that references an account that is also being created in the same call, the account must have a smaller index in the sObjects array than the contact does. The contact references the account by using an External ID field.
>
> You can't add a record that references another record of the same object type in the same call. For example, the Contact object has a Reports To field that is a reference to another contact. You can't create two contacts in one call if one contact uses the Reports To field to reference a second contact in the sObjects array. You can create a contact that references another contact that has been previously created.
>
> Records for different object types are broken into multiple chunks by Salesforce. A chunk is a subset of the sObjects input array and each chunk contains records of one object type. Data is committed on a chunk-by-chunk basis. Any Apex triggers related to the records in a chunk are invoked once per chunk. Consider an sObjects input array containing the following set of records.

Comment: Can you make the distinction between observed behavior (might change in the future) versus guaranteed (documented) behavior (less likely to change in the future) here? Or if it is documented add a link?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but would this be because Lists are an ordered collection so we should expect Triggers to execute `sObjectList[0]` through to `sObjectList.size()-1`?

Comment: Did you happen to test adding the contact before the account on the list? I suspect it fails, but it would be nice to know. xD

Comment: Yeah, some things cropped up but I did test it with reversed order and the triggers still fire in the order specified. The External Id voodoo doesn't work when reversing the order, however.

Comment: @DanJones Yeah it would be hard to imagine the code not written to loop from first to last. But the behavior then is a side effect of an implementation convenience rather than a designed API. So at some future date a bug fix or new feature might mean the code is changed to go in the reverse direction and if there is no internal test case (and no significant Hammer failures) the behavior will change. FYI, I'd expect JSON.serialise to output the fields in alphabetical order but they are in fact output in the reverse order; JSON says they are unordered so it shouldn't matter. Expect != actual.

Comment: @KeithC I think the SOAP API Developer Guide reference covers your concerns pretty well.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Excellent +1.