# How to store contact under account based on one custom field matching?

Tags: apex, trigger, class, list, scheduled

I use JitterBit Cloud Data loader to synchronize `Account`, `Contact`, `Opportunity` from xyz system to Salesforce with Daily Scheduled.

The `Account` object has a custom field named `Adrsearchkey__c`,
and the `Contact` object has a custom field named `AccAdrsearchkey__c` (which is the same as `Account.Adrsearchkey__c`).

Now, I need to save `Contact` under `Account` when `Contact.AccAdrsearchkey__c` matches  `Account.Adrsearchkey__c`.

I believe I need Apex Trigger for the same.

How can it be done?

Comment: should this be done going forward (or) do you have a need to look at existing records and update the account on a contact? can there be multiple accounts with same AccAdrsearchkey__c with matching AccAdrsearchkey__c  on contact?

Comment: yes, this process is automated let's say first of all Account inserted then after contact and then Opportunity....all of these have time gap of 1 hour..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this trick](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/set-relationship-via-name-pointing-field) to set the lookup using the name pointing reference (`Account`) without any need to query. Note that duplicate matches will result in an exception, so it's probably best to allow partial saves. The following method will get you started. Replace `External__c` and `AccountExternal__c` with the corresponding API Names from your org. I used them here to make the example more generic.

```
public static void associateExternalAccount(List<Contact> contacts)
{
    List<Contact> toUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    for (Contact record : trigger.new)
        toUpdate.add(new Contact(
            Id=record.Id, Account=new Account(External__c=record.AccountExternal__c)
            ));
    Database.update(toUpdate, /*allOrNone*/ false);
    // error handling advised
    // omitted here for brevity
}
```

You may wish to add some logic that [loops through the results to handle errors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm). This logic can be applied via `Apex Trigger` or `Batch Apex` with equal ease.

```
trigger Contact on Contact (after insert, after update)
{
    // trigger handler pattern advised
    // omitted here for brevity
    if (trigger.isAfter)
    {
        List<Contact> toUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        for (Contact record : trigger.new)
            if (record.AccountExternal__c != null && record.AccountId == null)
                toUpdate.add(record);
        ContactService.associateExternalAccount(toUpdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian !! can we use direct associateExternalAccount(toUpdate) ??

Comment: I don't understand your question. I would create a separate `Apex Class` called `ContactService` in which to place that method. You should put as little logic as possible in your trigger body.

Comment: Ohh OK.. i created one trigger and put these both code in it. so, thought we don't need ContactServices..

Comment: You really should not put your logic in the trigger body. I highly recommend you read **[Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)**.