# External Id salesforce

Tags: apex

Can we create child record using parent external Id?

ex:

> Inserting a CONTACT record by only using parent ACCOUNT record extenal Id not account Id.

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: Edited @MartinLezer

Comment: Are you using data-loader, UI or Custom apex?

Comment: Custom Apex @Mahmood

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Relationship Via Name Pointing Field?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133556/2995)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [external ID](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_import_general_what_is_an_external.htm&language=en&type=0) fields, Linking records without a Salesforce Id is main feature of external Ids.

Using that we can link the records in Apex as well as dataloader. Dataloader requires upsert operation.

Refer code from [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm) documentation. An example below.

```
Contact objContact = new Contact(
    LastName = 'Test Contact');

// Create the parent record reference.
// An account with this external ID value already exists.
// This sObject is used only for foreign key reference
// and doesn't contain any other fields.
Account accountReference = new Account(
    MyExtID__c='SAP111111');                

// Add the nested account sObject to the contact.
objContact.Account = accountReference;

// Create the contact.
Database.SaveResult results = Database.insert(objContact);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you can request an Account record from its external Id. For this sample I will call the external id field "External_Id__c":

```
Account account = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE External_Id__c = '123456789' LIMIT 1];
```

Then, you can insert your new contact by referring this account:

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.FirstName = 'Test';
contact.LatsName = 'Test';
contact.Email = 'test@test.com';
contact.AccountId = account.Id;

insert contact;
```

Comment: SOQL is not required for external id :)

Comment: @RahulSharma What do you mean by not required? How do you select the existing account record using only a field as external id?

Comment: Please see other answer.

Comment: @RahulSharma That's an awesome solution.

Comment: Yeah it's really handy.