# Interacting with join results through Apex

Tags: apex, soql

I understand it is possible to perform queries on related entities such as

```
SELECT (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

However, it is not obvious to me what's the result type of such a query if I try to assign it to a sObject / collection sObject.

Is that a `List<Account>` ? Is that a `List<Contact>` ?

Comment: List of accounts with a field Contacts pointing to a list of Contacts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of any query will always be of a type that corresponds to the top level `FROM` clause.

```
List<Account> records = [SELECT ... FROM Account];
```

It doesn't matter what's in the `SELECT` clause, nor any other clauses in your query. Sometimes, you might assign it to a single record rather than a list, but the `SObjectType` would remain the same:

```
Account record = [SELECT ... FROM Account LIMIT 1];
```

---

You can pull child records as if the related list were a field:

```
for (Account record : records)
{
    List<Contact> children = record.Contacts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the account.Contacts list is empty although I have created an account and attached two contacts

Comment: @Edmondo Did you attach them through the `AccountId` field or some other lookup?

Comment: Contact contact = new Contact(FirstName = 'Mark', LastName = 'Smith', Account = testAccount); doesn't work, why does one need to attach on the AccountId?

Comment: Using the accountID works, though it's not obvious for me why

Comment: @Edmondo The `Account` field is name pointing and using it to update the relationship has special rules. See also: **[Set Relationship Via Name Pointing Field?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133556/2995)**

Answer (score 1):

In that example, you probably will get a list of accounts.

```
List<Account> acc =[SELECT Id,Name, (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account];
```

Don't forget to add the 's'  (`Contacts`) at the end of the child object.