# Illegal assignment from String to Account

Tags: apex, unit-test

I was writing a test class to pass data into my controller. I received the following error:

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid field AccountId for SObject Account at
>   line 8 column 9

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
private class AccountContactControllerTest{

    static testMethod void myUnitTest1() {

        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'Project Account Test';
        **a.Parent = 'Parent Account';**
        a.Account_Email__c = 'anyuser@gmail.com';
        a.Site = 'www.google.com';
        a.Customer_ID__c = '1002';
        a.Project_Id__c = '1221.0001';
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.FirstName = 'Test first name';
        c.LastName = 'Test last name';
        c.Email = 'contactemail@gmail.com';
        c.Phone = '5546747737';
        insert c;

        sm1e__smEquipment__c assetTag = new sm1e__smEquipment__c();
        assetTag.Purchase_Date__c = date.newInstance(2016, 6, 1);
        assetTag.Name = '1021.0001 - Plant';
        assetTag.Plant_Business_Segment__c = 'EV';
        assetTag.Business_Segment__c = 'EV';
        assetTag.Operator__c = 'CalCom';
        assetTag.sm1e__Service_Region__c = 'Central';
        insert assetTag;

    }
  }
```

How do I pass test Data into the parent account field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create parent Account first, then use the id of the Parent at the child.

Sample code looks like:

```
        Account parentAcct = new Account ();
        parentAcct.Name = 'Parent Account 1';
        parentAcct.Customer_ID__c = '1005';
        insert parentAcct;


        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'Project Account Test';
        a.ParentId = parentAcct.id; //using parent account id
        a.Account_Email__c = 'anyuser@gmail.com';
        a.Site = 'www.google.com';
        a.Customer_ID__c = '1002';
        a.Project_Id__c = '1221.0001';
        insert a;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the A.Parent field is a field of type `lookup(Account)` then you'll want to use an Account ID instead of a string. You can create a dummy parent account and associate the parent account ID with that parent account field. Something like this:

```
Account parent = new Account(Name='Acme Corp.');
insert parent;
Account child = new Account(Name='Acme Child', Parent=parent.id);
insert child;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look in the documentation for [`Account`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm), the field's API Name is **`ParentId`**, not `Parent`. You set the `ParentId` using an Id value. `Parent` is a name-pointing reference which only takes an `Account` instance, but you can only [set a lookup using name pointing reference fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) when the object types differ:

> You can create related records that are up to 10 levels deep. Also, the related records created in a single call must have different sObject types.

This question might also help provide more context for what I mean when I say name pointing: [Set Relationship Via Name Pointing Field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133556/2995)