# Batch Insert child records with External Id

Tags: apex, batch, externalid

I'm creating a process to take records from a parent object and child object records and recreate them into different parent and child objects. This is for budgeting where we take a snapshot of records from "live" Salesforce and populate them into a static object that does not get updated so the budget stays the same.

I created a batch job that takes the 10,000 parent object records in 200 record batches and successfully creates them into the new object. The problem is I cannot figure out how to create the new 90,000 child records using a External Id.

My thought process is batch through the parents, then start another batch to get the child records. My batch method looks like this:

```
public static void createRevenueSchedule(List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> scope)
{    
    List<Revenue_Schedules__c> revScheduleToInsert = new List<Revenue_Schedules__c>();

    for(Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c rp : scope)
    {
        revScheduleToInsert.add(new Revenue_Schedules__c(
            Amount__c = rp.Amount__c,
            Date__c = rp.Date__c,
            Project_Revenue__r.External_Id__c = rp.Revenue_Pipeline__c //Id from old object is External Id for new object
        ));
    }
    try{
        insert revScheduleToInsert;        
    } catch (DmlException ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        System.debug('The following Exception has occured: ' + ex.getMessage() + ' at line ' + ex.getLineNumber());
    }            
}
```

The compile error I get says the field does not exist at the external Id line:

> Field does not exist: Project_Revenue__r.External_Id__c on Revenue_Schedules__c

Can you reference the external Id field without querying all the parent records?

Comment: If the first batch is successful the parent records should already be inserted so there would be separate DML statements right?

Comment: See also: [Set Relationship Via Name Pointing Field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133556/2995)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the parent by External ID, you have to create an sObject:

```
public static void createRevenueSchedule(List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> scope)
{    
    List<Revenue_Schedules__c> revScheduleToInsert = new List<Revenue_Schedules__c>();

    for(Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c rp : scope)
    {
        revScheduleToInsert.add(new Revenue_Schedules__c(
            Amount__c = rp.Amount__c,
            Date__c = rp.Date__c,
            Project_Revenue__r = new Revenue_Schedule__c(External_Id__c= rp.Revenue_Pipeline__c) //Id from old object is External Id for new object
        ));
    }
    try{
        insert revScheduleToInsert;        
    } catch (DmlException ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        System.debug('The following Exception has occured: ' + ex.getMessage() + ' at line ' + ex.getLineNumber());
    }            
}
```

Adjust the object/field names as appropriate.

Comment: the new SObject is the parent object?

Comment: @DanWooding the bit on line 10 is the change I proposed. I didn't know what the parent object is, so of course it should be adjusted appropriately, but this is how you do it in Apex Code. `LookupRelationship = new ParentType(externalIdField=externalidValue)`