# Insert two objects from JSON?

Tags: apex, json

How to map and insert the deserialized JSON Values for account and contact at the same time? each contact must related to account?

My class:

```
global class JSON2apex {

    global class JSON3apex {
        public String Name;
        public String Phone;
        public String Id;
        public List<Contacts> Contacts;
        public String Rating;
    }

    public class Contacts {
        public String AccountId;
        public String Id;
        public String LastName;
        public String FirstName;
    }

    public class Contacts_Z {
        public String AccountId;
        public String Id;
        public String LastName;
    }


    public static List<JSON3Apex> parse(String json) {
        return (List<JSON3Apex>) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<JSON3Apex>.class);
    }
}
```

And I'm calling this class from the below class:

```
public class accountcreate {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<object> saveChunk(String con){
        List<JSON2Apex.JSON3Apex> des = JSON2Apex.parse(con);
        system.debug('des2355'+des);
       // string malli='malli';
        return List<object>;
    }
}
```

And my JSON String is:

> ```
> [{
>     "Name": "Global Media",
>     "Phone": "(905) 555-1212",
>     "Id": "0016A0000035QXuQAM",
>     "Contacts": [{
>         "AccountId": "0016A0000035QXuQAM",
>         "Id": "0036A000002BnDpQAK",
>         "LastName": "White",
>         "FirstName": "Carole"
>     }, {
>         "AccountId": "0016A0000035QXuQAM",
>         "Id": "0036A000002BnDqQAK",
>         "LastName": "Amos",
>         "FirstName": "Jon"
>     }, {
>         "AccountId": "0016A0000035QXuQAM",
>         "Id": "0036A000002BnDoQAK",
>         "LastName": "Minor",
>         "FirstName": "Geoff"
>     }]
> }, {
>     "Name": "Acme",
>     "Phone": "(212) 555-5555",
>     "Id": "0016A0000035QXvQAM",
>     "Contacts": [{
>         "AccountId": "0016A0000035QXvQAM",
>         "Id": "0036A000002BnDsQAK",
>         "LastName": "Jones",
>         "FirstName": "Howard"
>     }, {
>         "AccountId": "0016A0000035QXvQAM",
>         "Id": "0036A000002BnDtQAK",
>         "LastName": "Tomlin",
>         "FirstName": "Leanne"
>     }, {
>         "AccountId": "0016A0000035QXvQAM",
>         "Id": "0036A000002BnDrQAK",
>         "LastName": "Stamos",
>         "FirstName": "Edward"
>     }]
> }, {
>     "Name": "salesforce.com",
>     "Phone": "(415) 901-7000",
>     "Id": "0016A0000035QXwQAM",
>     "Contacts": [{
>         "AccountId": "0016A0000035QXwQAM",
>         "Id": "0036A000002BnDuQAK",
>         "LastName": "Benioff",
>         "FirstName": "Marc"
>     }]
> }, {
>     "Name": "ravi",
>     "Phone": "8977007142",
>     "Id": "0016A00000AmKRyQAN",
>     "Contacts": [{
>         "AccountId": "0016A00000AmKRyQAN",
>         "Id": "0036A00000FWoavQAD",
>         "LastName": "reddy",
>         "FirstName": "Ravikumar"
>     }]
> }, {
>     "Name": "ins",
>     "Id": "0016A00000Apv84QAB",
>     "Contacts": [{
>         "AccountId": "0016A00000Apv84QAB",
>         "Id": "0036A00000FbtK4QAJ",
>         "LastName": "arjun"
>     }]
> }, {
>     "Name": "ims",
>     "Rating": "Hot",
>     "Id": "0016A00000ApBGDQA3",
>     "Contacts": [{
>         "AccountId": "0016A00000ApBGDQA3",
>         "Id": "0036A00000FbdpaQAB",
>         "LastName": "aru"
>     }]
> }, {
>     "Name": "ims1",
>     "Id": "0016A00000DHZdGQAX",
>     "Contacts": [{
>         "AccountId": "0016A00000DHZdGQAX",
>         "Id": "0036A00000FceFPQAZ",
>         "LastName": "malli"
>     }]
> }, {
>     "Name": "ims",
>     "Phone": "8977007142",
>     "Rating": "Hot",
>     "Id": "0016A00000ApBGhQAN",
>     "Contacts": [{
>         "AccountId": "0016A00000ApBGhQAN",
>         "Id": "0036A00000FbdpfQAB",
>         "LastName": "Malli"
>     }]
> }]
> ```

Comment: Why do your records already have ids if you're trying to insert them?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert records with their child records, by using an [External Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) which is set before the insert.

From the documentation:

> You can use external ID fields as foreign keys to create parent and child records of different sObject types in a single step instead of creating the parent record first, querying its ID, and then creating the child record. To do this:
>
> - Create the child sObject and populate its required fields, and optionally other fields.
> - Create the parent reference sObject used only for setting the parent foreign key reference on the child sObject. This sObject has only the external ID field defined and no other fields set.
> - Set the foreign key field of the child sObject to the parent reference sObject you just created.
> - Create another parent sObject to be passed to the insert statement. This sObject must have the required fields (and optionally other fields) set in addition to the external ID field.
> - Call insert by passing it an array of sObjects to create. The parent sObject must precede the child sObject in the array, that is, the array index of the parent must be lower than the child’s index.

Comment: Also related: [Set Relationship Via Name Pointing Field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133556/2995)

Comment: You can also create 'nested' records using the [composite request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_composite_resources.htm) or an [sObject Tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm) both provided by the REST API