# Getting error while relating child to parent using external id

Tags: apex, externalid, reference

I am referring to this link for relating parent data with external id. 
Link: [Click here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm)

**Sample code which I am trying:**

```
ysr_NS_test__Object_Child__c childObjectReference = new ysr_NS_test__Object_Child__c(Name='apex_child1');


ysr_NS_test__Object_Parent__c parentObjectForReference = 
    new ysr_NS_test__Object_Parent__c(ysr_NS_test__Parent_External_Id__c = '1');


childObjectReference.ysr_NS_test__Object_Parent__c = parentObjectForReference.Id;

try{
//insert childObjectReference;
    Database.SaveResult result = Database.insert(childObjectReference);

}
catch(Exception e){
    System.debug('Exception -' + e);
}
```

- ysr_NS_test  is the namespace.
- ysr_NS_test__Object_Child__c is the child object which has parent object lookup.
- ysr_NS_test__Object_Parent__c is the parent object which has external
  id.

I am expecting parent with external id 1 should bind to child object which is getting created(without querying the parent object).

**Update:**

Error I am getting:

> Exception -System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ysr_NS_test__Object_Parent__c]: [ysr_NS_test__Object_Parent__c]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing a parent record with its External Id field set doesn't magically tell you in memory what the Salesforce Id value is.

You need to set the relationship [using the name pointing field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/2995):

```
childObjectReference.ysr_NS_test__Object_Parent__r = new ysr_NS_test__Object_Parent__c(ysr_NS_test__Parent_External_Id__c = '1');
```

A bit easier to read with renamed objects for clarity:

```
childRecord.Parent__r = new Parent__c(External__c = '1');
```