# Illegal assignment from Sobject to Id : update a custom field

Tags: apex, dml

I have the following code

```
Map<Id,SICo_VoucherConso__c> mVoucherConso = new Map<Id,SICo_VoucherConso__c>([SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM SICo_VoucherConso__c WHERE Id ='XXXXX' ]);
Lead aLead = new Lead();
aLead.GodParent__c = mVoucherConso.get(aLead.CodePromoConso__c) ;
```

it is an example of what i really want to do. i have a lookup on lead for an sobject SICo_VoucherConso__c. I am trying to set the ownerId on the field godparent which is a lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to reference a field from the map's value:

```
aLead.GodParent__c = mVoucherConso.get(aLead.CodePromoConso__c).OwnerId;
```

Whenever you get an illegal assignment error, it's usually because you have the wrong data type.

Answer (score 2):

When you set lookups, you need to set the Id:

```
aLead.GodParent__c = mVoucherConso.get(aLead.CodePromoConso__c).OwnerId;
```

Before, you were trying to set the entire parent object. Notice the `.Id` at the end. Note, however, that this parent record can be null, which would lead to a null parent. So it would be better to check that the record does, in fact exist, before trying to dereference a field on it.

```
SICo_VoucherConso__c parent = mVoucherConso.get(aLead.CodePromoConso__c);
aLead.GodParent__c = (parent == null) ? null : parent.OwnerId;
```

Note that there are circumstances where [you can set the entire parent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133556/2995), but it is a different mechanic with very specific requirements for it to work. This functionality is not likely to be a good fit here.