# How to use parent object Reference in child

Tags: apex

Here is my problem. I'm trying to establish a parent child relationship like the below and want to use the OBJECT reference and NOT the ID reference.

I have created a custom lookup field on Contact called MyAccount that looks up to Account and want to populate that field using the object reference.

```
Account a = [SELECT ID, NAME FROM Account WHERE NAME = 'TEST ACCOUNT' LIMIT 1];
Sobject c = Schema.getglobalDescribe().get('Contact').newSObject();
c.put('lastname', 'sobject test');
c.putSobject('myaccount__r', a);
insert c;
```

When I query the contact after it's being inserted, however the reference is NOT populated. It's showing as NULL. How to fix this? Again, I want to use parent record reference and NOT ID reference.

Note: this works for Standard fields - for example if I do something like.
`c.putSobject('Account', a)` - this works perfectly

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to reproduce the behavior you are claiming with using `putSObject()` using a standard relationship field. It'll compile and run, but when I re-query the inserted contact, the relationship field is null.

Also, from [Set Relationship Via Name Pointing Field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/set-relationship-via-name-pointing-field), the blog post by Bob Buzzard referenced in that question, and my own experimentation, it does seem that this only works when you use a field on the parent object that's marked as being an external Id (and that external Id seems to be the *only* thing that can be set in the object reference).

From that, I have to conclude that what you're asking for is not currently possible (Winter '21, API v50.0)