# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, You can't associate a private contact with an account

Tags: apex

I'm having issues when trying to create a test for the following method

```
public class Manager {

    @TestVisible
    private static AccountContactRelation createRelation(Account practice, Contact contact) {
        AccountContactRelation relation = new AccountContactRelation();  
        relation.AccountId = practice.Id;
        relation.ContactId = contact.Id;

        insert relation;
        return relation;
    }

}
```

```
@isTest
public class TestManager {

 @isTest
    public static void testCreateRelation() {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Account Test');
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact(FirstName='Contact', LastName='Test', Account=a);
        insert c;

        AccountContactRelation r = Manager.createRelation(a, c);
        System.assertEquals(r.AccountId, a.Id);
        System.assertEquals(r.ContactId, c.Id);

        AccountContactRelation dbRelation = [SELECT AccountId, ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE AccountId = :a.Id AND ContactId = :c.Id];
        System.assert(dbRelation != null);        
    }

}
```

When I try to run the test above, I'm having the following error on the console

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, You can't associate a private contact with an account.: [ContactId]

The only thing on my instance out of the ordinary is that I had activated the option to support multiple accounts per contact

**UPDATE**

I also tried another approach suggested by @Derek F sending the Id specifically, and still doesn't work. The same error appears

```
@isTest
public class TestManager {

 @isTest
    public static void testCreateRelation() {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Account Test');
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact(FirstName='Contact', LastName='Test', AccountId=a.Id);
        insert c;

        AccountContactRelation r = Manager.createRelation(a, c);
        System.assertEquals(r.AccountId, a.Id);
        System.assertEquals(r.ContactId, c.Id);

        AccountContactRelation dbRelation = [SELECT AccountId, ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE AccountId = :a.Id AND ContactId = :c.Id];
        System.assert(dbRelation != null);        
    }

}
```

Comment: I added Both "Manager" and "TestManager" (the updated one) class to a develop sandbox didn't get the error you mentioned above ("You can't associate a private contact with an account"). I got a dupliacted relation error, but because your are inserting the relation in both "TestManager" and "Manager" classes

Comment: Do you have a trigger or flow that is doing something with the contact? This error happens when you create a contact without a AccountId associated, and try to create a AccountContactRelation using this contact.  It looks like something is removing the accountId from the contact before insert.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is that you are trying to add second relation between same Account and Contact. Your Contact has already relation to this account (because when you are creating contact you're DIRECTLY relating to an Account) and later you try to again relate (this time indirectly) contact to the same Account.

Create second Account and try to relate Contact to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your test method, on the line

```
Contact c = new Contact(FirstName='Contact', LastName='Test', Account=a);
```

Trying to set parent relationships like that (parent = objectInstance) only works when you're dealing with an external id field (and objectInstance must *only* have that external Id field populated, and the external Id must be unique across all records of that object).

[This blog post by Bob Buzzard in 2012 is still relevant](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2012/03/create-parent-and-child-records-in-one.html). There's also [this SFSE question from 2016 that references it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/set-relationship-via-name-pointing-field).

The way you're trying to do things causes the test contact you're inserting to not have `AccountId` populated. If a Contact doesn't have `AccountId` populated, it's a "private" contact and cannot have any ACR records created for it.

The fix here is simple. Instead of trying to take the shortcut, just add a few extra characters to set the relationship field (AccountId) instead of the name-pointing reference (Account).

```
Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = 'Contact', LastName = 'Test', AccountId = a.Id);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @derek 
But actually, initially that was my approach, but the error is the same
`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, You can't associate a private contact with an account.: `
I suspect that's something that has to do with the `multiple accounts support`