# Use field as relationship connection between objects

Tags: custom-object, relationships, master-detail

I am struggling with a seemingly easy task:

I need to connect Account Objects with a custom object created for reviews.
One Account can receive multiple reviews and they should be shown in the account details view.

Now I would think that a master-detail relation suits best, since the reviews can be deleted if the parent Account gets deleted as well. My question now is:

How can I choose a field which acts as the connection between the two objects?
I have a field called customerID in both objects, and want to link every review to its parent account when the customerID matches.

How would one go about it?

Comment: This isn't out of the box - you have to build a process that establishes the relationship based on your field. Take a look at [Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/automate_business_processes) or [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

Comment: You mean I can not connect child objects with parent objects based on one field? For example link every child object with customerID 123 to an Account with customerID 123?

Comment: You can connect them by using tools and building the process that does the connection. You can also connect them manually in the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

I would say one of the primary considerations for whether or not you should use Master-Detail is sharing. If you want the child (many) object to be visible to everyone, regardless of whether they can see the parent or not, Lookup is best. If you want the child visibility to be controlled by parent, then Master-Detail may well be the correct choice.

Comment: Based on your answer, I would definetly go with Master-Detail then. But is it possible to connect child objects with parent objects based on one field? For example link every child object with customerID 123 to an Account with customerID 123?

Comment: Relationships work based on record ids. That's what gets actually stored in the database. If you want to populate those based on some external relationship, [that can also be done](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133556/2995).