# Test class error: 'Attempt to de-reference a null object' when inserting a record with a lookup

Tags: apex, unit-test

Error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Account__c]: [Account__c]

Test class:

```java
@isTest
public class FacilityTriggerTest {

    @isTest
    public static void updateagreementTest() {
        Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agreement = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
        agreement.Name = 'Test Agreement';
        insert agreement;

        Facility__c facility = new Facility__c();
        //facility.Name = 'Test Facility';
        facility.Agreement__c = agreement.Id;
        //facility.Davita_legal_entity__c = 'Test Legal Entity';
        //facility.Facility_Division__c = 'Test Division';
        //facility.Facility_Group__c = 'Test Group';
        //.Davita_legal_Entity_Name__c = 'Test Legal Entity Name';
        //facility.Facility_Name__c = 'Test Facility Name';
        //facility.Facility_Number__c = '123456';
        insert facility;

        List<Facility__c> facilityList = new List<Facility__c>();
        facilityList.add(facility);

        Test.startTest();
        FacilityHandler.updateagreement(facilityList);
        Test.stopTest();

        Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c updatedAgreement = [SELECT Id, Facility_Name_for_Template__c, Facility_Number_for_Template__c, Division_Name__c, Palmer_Group__c, Davita_Legal_Entity_2__c
                                                      FROM Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c
                                                      WHERE Id = :agreement.Id];

        System.assertEquals(facility.Davita_legal_entity__c, updatedAgreement.Davita_Legal_Entity_2__c);
        //Changed as Divisin__c to Division_Name__c on 28/06/2023
        System.assertEquals(facility.Facility_Division__c, updatedAgreement.Division_Name__c);
        System.assertEquals(facility.Facility_Group__c, updatedAgreement.Palmer_Group__c);
        System.assertEquals(facility.Davita_legal_Entity_Name__c, updatedAgreement.Davita_Legal_Entity_2__c);
        System.assertEquals(facility.Facility_Name__c, updatedAgreement.Facility_Name_for_Template__c);
        System.assertEquals(facility.Facility_Number__c, updatedAgreement.Facility_Number_for_Template__c);
    }

    @isTest
    public static void facilityMethodTest() {
        Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agreement = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
        agreement.Name = 'Test Agreement';
        insert agreement;

        Facility__c facility = new Facility__c();
        //facility.Name = 'Test Facility';
        facility.Agreement__c = agreement.Id;
        facility.Account__r.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert facility;

        List<Facility__c> newFacilityList = new List<Facility__c>();
        newFacilityList.add(facility);

        List<Facility__c> oldFacilityList = new List<Facility__c>();

        Test.startTest();
        FacilityHandler.facilityMethod(newFacilityList, oldFacilityList, true, false);
        Test.stopTest();

        Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c updatedAgreement = [SELECT Id, Facility_Name__c
                                                      FROM Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c
                                                      WHERE Id = :agreement.Id];

        System.assertEquals(facility.Account__r.Name, updatedAgreement.Facility_Name__c);
    }
}
```

Apex class:

```java
trigger FacilityTrigger on Facility__c(after insert, after update, after delete) {

    if (trigger.isAfter && (trigger.IsInsert || trigger.IsUpdate)) {
        FacilityHandler.updateagreement(trigger.New);
    }
    if (trigger.isAfter && (trigger.IsInsert || trigger.IsUpdate || trigger.IsDelete)) {
        FacilityHandler.facilityMethod(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.IsInsert, trigger.IsUpdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: STACK TRACE :-
Class.FacilityTriggerTest.facilityMethodTest: line 50, column 1
Class.FacilityTriggerTest.updateagreementTest: line 19, column 1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't populate a lookup field via another field, only by the Id of the record. So you can't do `facility.Account__r.Name = 'Test Account';`. You also can't link to a record that is not in the database yet.

First, insert the account:

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
insert a;
```

Then use that to get the Id:

```
facility.Account__c = a.Id;
```

Comment: There's some nuance here that I think is worthy of note. While it is true that we do need to have a record inserted before we can set **and persist** a relationship to it on another record (this is not a requirement if there is no DML/queries involved and everything stays "in-memory"), [we can use external Ids to set relationships](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/set-relationship-via-name-pointing-field). I don't think OP is ready to use that though (and it doesn't really apply well to this particular situation regardless).

Comment: This also works with some (if not all) fields that have the "idLookup" property (looking in the "Object Reference for the Salesforce Platform" documentation) e.g. `insert new Account(Name = 'test acc', Owner = new User(Username = 'existing.person@company.tld'));`. I've personally used this approach in some of my unit tests (updating pricebooks in a unit test so I can actually _use_ them, setting record types on test records without the need to get the SObject describe info).