# Apex Bulkification Issue

Tags: apex, bulkification

I have an `SObject` variable in which I'm adding the field api names and the values respectively as it acts as a Map and later adding it to a `List<SObject>` variable. The below code works as expected.

```
String sObjectType = 'Account';
List<SObject> myList = new List<SObject>();
Schema.SObjectType currentObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType);
SObject newRecordToBeCreated = currentObjectType.newSObject();
newRecordToBeCreated.put('RecordTypeId', currentObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('AccRecType').getRecordTypeId());
myList.add(newRecordToBeCreated);
insert myList;
```

My apex logic will

1. Try to find all the necessary fields from the `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` class of x object
2. Populates test data based on the field's `Schema.DisplayType` using the `SObject` variable (like shown above)
3. Add's the `SObject` variable to the `List<SObject>` variable (also shown above)
4. Finally return the `List<SObject>` for insertion from different class(es)

### Issue:

The issue is with the Lookup or `REFERENCE` field. I know I first have to insert the Parent SObject, grab the Id and put it in the SObject variable. However, my whole logic is inside of a for loop (going through a list of fields).

Also my method will be used to create multiple records which will become a for loop inside of a for loop.

**Is there a way to avoid the DML statement inside the inner for loop at least in this scenario?**

(Not sure how to frame the question/title, so open to suggestions)

Comment: well, the fflib UnitOfWork Pattern abstracts all of this so you can can registerNew parent, child, granchild records without having to remember any ids in code; but in lieu of that, I'd suggest looking at open source test data generator libraries rather than reinventing this wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the heart of your dilemma is this:
How can we know, programmatically, that two records are supposed to be related to one another?

Using Salesforce-generated Ids is one answer to that question, the natural approach. As you've posited, it's an issue when you want to create parents *and child* records because you'd have DML inside of a loop.

The solution I've used in the past is to separate the creation of the in-memory SObject instances from the DML aspect. That requires finding another way to programmatically relate two records. Using an external id field could help (see [this question of Adrian's from 2016](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/set-relationship-via-name-pointing-field)), but I think a more general solution is to take advantage of the fact that we can use SObjects as the key for a Map.

In short:

- Use a subset of the parent object's field to define a "key"
- Put the parent records into a `Map<SObject, SObject>`, which you'll later use for DML (`insert myParentMap.values();`)
- At the same time, prepare a `Map<SObject, List<SObject>>` which has the parent's "key" and stores a list of child records

You'll be able to insert your parent records and get your Ids (automatically set in the parent instances in `myParentMap` because of the "store by reference" nature of non-primitives in lists/maps).

Then you can simply loop over the parent keys, fetch the parent record (with Id), and do a nested loop over the child records to set their relationship field.

example (pseudocode):

```java
// Helper method to handle generating the key so the code can be reused
// What the "key" contains is going to differ from situation to situation
// Basically, it needs to be like a database primary key, something that
//   can uniquely identify every record
public SObject generateKey(SObject target, List<String> keyFields) {
    SObject key = target.getSObjectType.newSObject();

    for(String field :keyFields) {
        key.put(field, target.get(field));
    }

    return key;
}

Map<SObject, SObject> parentsByParentKeyMap = new Map<SObject, SObject>();
Map<SObject, List<SObject>> childrenByParentKeyMap = new Map<SObject, List<SObject>>();

// Create the in-memory instances
for(SObjectType parentSObjType :someListOfParents) {
    SObject parent = parentSObjType.newSObject();

    for(String parentField :parentValuesByField.keySet()) {
        parent.put(parentField, parentValuesByField.get(parentField));
    }
    
    SObject parentKey = generateKey(parent, new List<String>{'Name', 'Region__c'});

    // One important thing to keep in mind is that once you use something
    //   as a key in a map, that object instance should _never_ be modified
    parentsByParentKeyMap.put(parentKey, parent);

    // Again, thanks to the store-by-reference nature, it doesn't matter if
    //   we create this list now and populate it later.
    // Separately defining the childList saves us the trouble of fetching
    //   it in the child loop
    List<SObject> childList = new List<SObject>();
    childrenByParentKeyMap.put(parentKey, childList);

    for(SObjectType childSObjType :someListOfChildren) {
        SObject child = childSObjType.newSObject();

        for(String childField :childValuesByField.keySet()) {
            child.put(childField, childValuesByField.get(childField));
        }

        childList.add(child);
    }
}

// Perform DML for the parents
insert parentsByParentKeyMap.values();

// Go back and set relationships for the children
// And gather them all in a single list so you can do a single insert
List<SObject> flatChildrenList = new List<SObject>();
for(SObject key :parentsByParentKeyMap.keySet()) {
    SObject parent = parentsByParentKeyMap.get(key);

    for(SObject child :childrenByParentKeyMap.get(key)) {
        child.put('Parent__c', parent.get('Id'));

        flatChildrenList.add(child);
    }
}

// Finally, DML the children
insert flatChildrenList;
```

This does assume that you'll be creating the parent instances first

Comment: N.B. this is more or less what the fflib UnitOfWork does

Comment: It would be good, since you mention using an `SObject` as a map key, to say that the `SObject` state must not change once used as a key since such changes prevent the `get` from functioning correctly (typically causing a map lookup failure unless you `System.debug` out the map first, since this happens to recalculate the bucket mapping).

Comment: (BTW, and this isn't important for the Q&A but rather I am curious; any reason you do not have a space after the `for` loop's `:` iterator operator? It makes this seem to be the same as a SOQL binding variable, which it isn't...)

Comment: @PhilW I did, in fact, mention that the SObject key must not be modified (in a comment in my example code, at an appropriate location). The for loop thing is just code style (shrug).

Comment: Ah, I did not focus on the comments in the pseudocode. It's one of those points I would have covered in a **Note**, but to each their own.

Comment: @DerekF Thank you so much, this helped me solve the issue.